# Rudin Algebraic completion of the complex field proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

In Rudin, he is trying to prove that
$$P(x)=\sum_{0}^{n}a_kz^k=0$$
for some $a_k,z\in\mathbb{C}$.  What I'm really confused about is the first step of his proof, where he's constructed this inequality using $|z|=R$
$$|P(z)|\ge R^n[1-|a_{n-1}|R^{-1}-\dots-|a_0|R^{-n}]$$
This doesn't seem to be the reverse triangle inequality, and I'm really stumped as to how this has come about.  It also doesn't seem to be anything specific to the radius of convergence, and I think here he's using $R$ just as an arbitrary constant.  I have no idea where to even begin trying to construct this on my own, so any pointers would be great.

Comment: If $a_n=1$, then this really is the reverse triangle inequality (along with a factorization of the leading power $R^n$). For example, $|a_2z^2+a_1z+a_0|\geq |a_2z^2|-|a_1z|-|a_0|=|a_2|R^2-|a_2|R-|a_0|$, and now just factor the highest power $R^2$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo is it just using a double negative?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: $|x-y|\ge||x|-|y||$, then $|x-(-y)|\ge||x|-|-y||$, so $|x+y|\ge ||x|-|y||$

Comment: yea and in particular, $|x+y|\geq |x|-|y|$, so $|x+y+z|\geq |x+y|-|z|\geq |x|-|y|-|z|$, and so on for more terms (a super formal proof requires induction of course).

Comment: fantastic, can you write it as an answer and I'll give it a tick?  Can't believe I didn't see that for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reverse triangle inequality $|x+y|\geq |x|-|y|$, we can extend to more terms as $|x+y+z|\geq |x+y|-|z|\geq |x|-|y|-|z|$, and more generally by induction, $\left|\sum_{j=0}^nc_j\right|\geq |c_i|-\sum_{j\neq i}|c_j|$ for any $i$. In particular in the polynomial case, taking $i=n$ and supposing $a_n=1$ (you assume $a_n\neq 0$ and then without loss of generality, rescale to set $a_n=1$), we get (after factoring $R^n$, where $R:=|z|$)
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k\right|&\geq |z|^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k||z|^{k}=R^n\left[1-|a_{n-1}|R^{-1}-\dots - |a_n|R^{-n}\right].
\end{align}